# Python: How to output function results to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame with flavour peptides and their amino acid sequence and I'm trying to **count the occurrence of each amino acid and store it in a new dataFrame**. To start with, I'm just working with a very small dataFrame with only 5 rows. For my actual dataFrame the sequences can be longer than 1 character and if, for example the string is: `'RPFFLR'` then I'd want it to count: 2*F, 1*L, 1*P and 2*R.

This is the initial dataFrame:

```
    ID               Name Sequence
0      1  bitter amino acid        R
3      4  bitter amino acid        P
6      7  bitter amino acid        F
36   172  bitter amino acid        L
438  105  bitter amino acid        V
```

I have the following code:

```
def countAA(Bseq, ref):
    countF = [0]
    countL = [0]
    countP = [0]
    countR = [0]
    countV = [0]
    Bseq = Baadata.Sequence
    ref = 'ADEFGHIKLMPQRSTVWY'
    for i in Bseq:
        for c in ref:
            if ref[4] in Bseq:
                countF += 1
            elif ref[9] in Bseq:
                countL += 1
            elif ref[11] in Bseq:
                countP += 1
            elif ref[13] in Bseq:
                countR += 1
            elif ref[16] in Bseq:
                countV += 1
    return [countF, countL, countP, countR, countV]

Bseq = Baadata.Sequence
for i in Bseq:
    ref = 'ADEFGHIKLMPQRSTVWY'
    Baa = countAA(Bseq, ref)

Bdf = pd.DataFrame((Baa),
                   index=['F', 'L', 'P', 'R', 'V'],
                   columns=['Bitter']
                   )
print(Bdf)
```

For this small input the expected output would be:

```
     Bitter
F    1
L    1
P    1
R    1
V    1
```

*What am I doing wrong as my code isn't counting the characters?*

Comment: Please add the output you expected to get

Comment: Your `countAA` function has a bug. You overwrite the input `Bseq` in the 6th line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a DataFrame is the best structure for your output? If all you want is a count of each character in the `Sequences` column, you can do it very easily using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
Bdf = Counter("".join(Baadata.Sequence))
```

example

```
Baadata = pd.DataFrame(["asd", "fdf", "s", "xxxxxxx"], columns=['Sequence'])
Counter("".join(Baadata.Sequence))
```

outputs

```
Counter({'a': 1, 's': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 2, 'x': 7})
```

Comment: My actual data is ~400 rows and more complicated. I also want to do other things with the output. I'm just trying to get it to work on something simple first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

1) first group your data based on 'Name' and 'Sequence' (I assume you have only a few sequences)
`df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Sequence']).count().reset_index()`

2) Subsequently pivot the table to get your intende result
`df.pivot(index='Sequence', columns='Name', values='ID')`